# Hover link text and icon

Tags: html, css

I got some text after two contact icons. What I want is both the icon AND the text to be a link, so that when the icon OR the text is hovered they both light up.

At this point I am only able to achive this effect on the envelope example, but as you can tell the text conflicts with the icon itself.

```css
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
}

.fa {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  color: #282828;
}

.fa:hover { color: #F0F0F0; }

.fa-envelope-o:hover,
.fa-phone:hover {
  background: #282828;
  color: white;    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com" class="fa fa-envelope-o">example@gmail.com</a>
<br>
<a href="tel:1234567" class="fa fa-phone"></a>1234567
```

Comment: only icon should have effect, on hovering either icon or text?

Comment: Both icon and the text, but the text should not overlap the icon in any way

Comment: How about this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/rz8mdq2L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below changes in HTML with CSS hover effect for both span and anchor element

```css
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
}

.fa {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  color: #282828;
}

.fa:hover { color: #F0F0F0; }

.fa-envelope-o:hover,
.fa-phone:hover {
  background: #282828;
  color: white;    
}

span:hover a{
  background: #282828;
  color: white;
}

span:hover{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
<span><a href="mailto:example@gmail.com" class="fa fa-envelope-o"></a>example@gmail.com</span>
<br>
<span><a href="tel:1234567" class="fa fa-phone"></a>1234567</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap them in 'span' tags. Also the 'fa fa-font' should start with 'i class'

```
    <span class='mud'><a href="tel:1234567"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>1234567</span>
```

Then add to your CSS the following.

```
    span.mud:hover {
        background: #282828;
        color: white; 
    }
```

Hope this helps you. Have a great day.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but this is not correct either. I want it like the envelope example, without the text overlapping the icon

Comment: Updated the code. should work for you now. moved the closing 'a' tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making both the icon and the link `<spans>`, and give the link `<span>` a class (I've given it the class`link` for the example):

```
<span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span>
<span class="link">example@gmail.com</span>
```

And wrap them both in an `<a>` tag, also with a class, (I've used `outer`):

```
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com" class="outer">
  <span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span>
  <span class="link">example@gmail.com</span>
</a>
```

And apply the hover styles from that.

```
.outer { text-decoration: none; font-size: 15px; color: #282828; }
.outer:hover .link { color: #F0F0F0; }
.outer:hover .fa { background: #282828; color: white; }
```

This allows the rest of your CSS to be simplified to the following:

```
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
```

```css
.outer {text-decoration: none; font-size: 15px; color: #282828;}
.outer:hover .link { color: #F0F0F0; }
.outer:hover .fa { background: #282828; color: white; }
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com" class="outer">
  <span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span>
  <span class="link">example@gmail.com</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something...

```css
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
}

span {
  margin-left:15px;
  }

.fa {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  color: #282828;
}

.fa:hover { color: #F0F0F0; }

.fa-envelope-o:hover,
.fa-phone:hover {
  background: #282828;
  color: white;    
}

.fa-envelope-o::before {

    content: "\f003";
    margin-left: 7px;

}

.fa-phone::before {

    content: "\f095";
    margin-left: 8px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com" class="fa fa-envelope-o"><span>example@gmail.com</span></a>
<br>
<a href="tel:1234567" class="fa fa-phone"><span>1234567</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="tel:1234567" class="fa fa-phone">1234567</a>
```

As seen above, you need to put the number within the 'a' tag.

Comment: No, phone is not correct either. They both icon and text should light up when either of them are hovered